# ¿Cómo genero en Power BI una tabla con un solo registro que acceda a una vista en una bd SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, json, report, powerbi, powerquery

Tengo un archivo pbix que se conecta a dos vistas almacenadas en una bd SQL Server 2008. Este archivo se conecta al servidor mediante una conexión odbc. Sin embargo, al momento que reviso el código de una de las tablas utilizadas, veo que utiliza un método de un JSON para poder arrojar un solo registro:

[image: Código Power Query para tabla "Medidas Ultima Campaña"]

[image: Tabla generada con un solo registro]

Si revisamos el modelo, se ve a la tabla Medidas Utlima Campaña, no relacionada con las otras dos tablas generadas por las vistas consumidas de la bd SQL Server 2008. Estas últimas se relacionan con una tabla de apoyo, creada con Power BI.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué es exactamente ese código que al parecer consume un JSON? Si quisiera conectarme a otras vistas o procedimientos y crear nuevas medidas en la tabla Medias Ultima Campaña ¿Cómo podría replicar el código de JSON de ser necesario?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esa tabla que estás revisando es una entrada manual de datos, no es una consulta la base de datos. Por ello lo ves de dicha manera.

Al momento de conectarte por odbc, puedes ejecutar una consulta contra el motor para obtener la información deseada. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. La tabla [Medias Ultima Campaña] es una entrada manual, pero esta tablilla utiliza la data de las otras dos vistas  (VW_FACT_xxxx) las cuales si se conectan a una bd. Mi duda no es por aquella tablilla, por ende mi pregunta ¿Qué es exactamente ese código que al parecer consume un JSON?

Comment: Para que el formato de lo que construis manualmente sea liviano, es tomado como JSON desde la entrada manual. Por eso el primer paso aparece de dicha forma.